# NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/ Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-templates

Here is my stack trace of exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Joga\testenv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner response = 
get_response(request) File "C:\Users\Joga\testenv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response response = 
self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) File 
"C:\Users\Joga\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 
113, in _get_response response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs) File 
"C:\Users\Joga\Desktop\project\djangonautic\accounts\views.py", line 24, in 
login_view return redirect(request.POST.get('next')) File 
"C:\Users\Joga\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 41, in 
redirect return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs)) File 
"C:\Users\Joga\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 131, in 
resolve_url return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs) File 
"C:\Users\Joga\testenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in 
reverse return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, 
**kwargs)) File "C:\Users\Joga\testenv\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix raise 
NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/ Exception Value: Reverse 
for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

after reading the exception, I am pretty sure the
`return redirect(request.POST.get('next'))` is causing error. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Django default login page redirect to `next`, which is POSTed by the form, and defaults to `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` which you may have set to `""`.

I suggest you to read carefully the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView